# WordPress.com blog migration to self hosted WordPress website

Tags: migration, blog, wordpress.com-hosting

I have my blogs on `wordpress.com` (e.g. `test.wordpress.com`). I want to migrate all those blogs to my self hosted WordPress website. Is this possible?

Is there any plugin in WordPress or do I need to develop any API?

Comment: Who knows? you will need to define what is it that you want to migrate. Just content? theme? theme settings? something additional?

Comment: Please [merge your accounts](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 1):

It's easy and possible. all you need to do is export your content from wp.com (wp-admin/tools/export) and import it to your new website (wp-admin/tools/import).

That should be all, I would also suggest that you purchase https://en.support.wordpress.com/site-redirect/ so if a visitor goes to mywebsite.wordpress.com, they get redirected to mywebsite.com

Answer (score 1):

Yes You can.

Login to your WordPress.com account and switch to the site that you want to migrate.

Click on WP Admin menu from Left Navigation

wp-admin will be opened in a new tab, go to that tab and click on Tools > Export

Use the second option which will give you an xml file

Save that xml file to your computer.

Now login to your self hosted wordpress

Navigate to Tools > Import

Click on WordPress importer

Install the Plugin & Run Import with the file you've downloaded from wp.com site

And you're done...!